# Include parser regex

Tags: c, regex, string, text, include

I'm trying to make small program which will tell mi which files are and which files aren't included in my application. I tried to use this Regex:

```
#include (<|")([^\r\n;#">]*)(>|")
```

It works good but it also gets wrong output as correct:

```
#include <stdio.h"
```

This is impossible in C compiler.
So question is: does anybody know how to edit my regex correctly? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include (?:<([^\r\n;#">]*)>|"([^\r\n;#">]*)")
```

So instead of accepting `[<"]x[>"]` you accept `<x>` or `"x"`. [Example](http://regexr.com?31q9n).

Answer (score 1):

I tried in different ways, but seems there is no easy way, at least I didn't see that.

1. `#include (<|")([^\r\n;#">]*)(\1)`
   Yeah, that works really fine for `"cstdio"`, neither `<cstdio>`. Fail.
2. `#include (<(?=[^\r\n;#">]*>)|"(?=[^\r\n;#">]*"))([^\r\n;#">]*)(>|")`
   Here we check if `<` or `"` are forwarded by matching symbol. Heavy.
3. `#include (<[^\r\n;#">]*>|"[^\r\n;#">]*")`
   Just check both cases, if we are having `<...>` or `"..."`.

Waiting for the better answer, I'm interested too. Bit I'm thinking, this'll go fine already.

P.S.: In cases 2 and 3 we should better to save `[^\r\n;#">]*` in a separate string and concat to other parts of regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include\s{1,}(<|\")[^(>&\")]*(>|\")
```

Comment: While this might be a bit more accurate on the library name, this does not solve the `<foo"` problem at all.